# Jenkins Automation help required

Tags: jenkins, pvcs

I have been assigned a task to do build automation using jenkins which should perform checkout, compile & build automatically.

Existing set up - Currently we have PVCS installed in one of our AIX server where build process(checkout,compile,build) is automated using ant script.

I have installed jenkins in my windows server.

How do i get the code into my windows server from PVCS which resides in AIX server to perform build through jenkins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi AMACB,

I have installed the PVCS plugin to my jenkins.
I created a job under Freestyle Project. 
It requires project root, archive root, PVCS workspace, and other details to configure PVCS in that job.
I am not sure where can i get PVCS workspace, project root & archive root details
is pvcs workspace nothing but the URL that we use in browser to open pvcs repository?

Answer (score 0):

As I posted on [CodeRanch where you posted the same question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/661637/tools/Jenkins-Automation), you need to install the [PVCS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PVCS+SCM) for Jenkins.

Comment: You provided a link to stackoverflow. For other users having this problem please also post your solution here.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the link. The answer was "use the PVCS plugin."